# my videos are not displaying description please assist am not an expert

Tags: php, html

please how can i echo description of the video in my below code. The code is only displaying video no description please assist thanks am not a php expert.
Below is my display.php file

```
 <?php
include("config.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="videoal">
    <?php
      $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT location,description FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)) {
    ?>
      <div class="video">
        <video controls>
          <source src="<?php echo $row['location'];?>" type="video/mp4">
            <meta content="<?php echo $row['description'];?>"  />
        </video>
      </div>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code here is for my style.css i wish you assist me please.
i want my to display video the a description below it. Thanks.
my style.css

```
#videoal {

}

#videoal div.video {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#videoal div.video video {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: am very new please give a guide my friend or a code

Comment: I am being a little picky ___BUT___ if `$maxsize = 8388608; // 8MB` and your message says `if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) { echo "File too large. File must be less than 5MB.";}` ???

Comment: Also it is always a good idea to check `$_FILES['file']['error']` before assuming the upload actually completed correctly. See [The PHP manual Page for uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: _and i got a folder in project called(video)_ BUT Do you have a folder called (videos) as that is what you are using in `$target_dir = "videos/";`

Comment: Also ... Have you checked your error logs

Comment: Also echoing error messages into the `<head>` section is never a good idea

Comment: yes i got videos not video

Comment: remember i uploaded a video of 1.3Mb succesfully

Comment: remember i uploaded a video of 1.3Mb succesfully

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size for PHP accordingly, either in your php.ini or .htaccess file.

[Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/increase-upload-size-in-your-phpini

Comment: amazing bro i wish you write for me the short code i should add or correct please i beg my friend

Comment: These are not coding changes. These are suggested amendments to your `php.ini` file.

Comment: remember i uploaded a video of 1.3Mb succesfully

Comment: In your root web directory, you may have a .htaccess file if you are using apache, add these lines: php_value upload_max_filesize 10M (new line:) php_value post_max_size 10M More info on the links attached to the reply above

Comment: worked excellent php-ini changed max upload size to 10M and post max 10M.

Comment: Awesome! Please remember to mark the accepted answer so other users with the same issue may benefit as well.